# Is $ the equivalent of \ in the replace string of a RegEx match (using Notepad++)?

Tags: excel, regex, notepad++

I used some Excel formulas to generate 172 lines of SQL code for a query.  I paste Excel stuff into Notepad++ to clean up anything that needs cleaning up before pasting it into SSMS.  When pasted into Notepad++, Excel put quotes around all of the strings.  I'm used to inconsistent behavior from Excel which is why I know I'm usually going to have to paste into NPP to get something I can use.  For context, here is what I got.

```
"   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR([StemLength]*5)/5 AS decimal(9,1)) = 8.8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8.8'"
"   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR([StemLength]*5)/5 AS decimal(9,1)) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9'"
"   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR([StemLength]*5)/5 AS decimal(9,1)) = 9.2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9.2'"
"   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR([StemLength]*5)/5 AS decimal(9,1)) = 9.4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9.4'"
"   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR([StemLength]*5)/5 AS decimal(9,1)) = 9.6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9.6'"
"   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR([StemLength]*5)/5 AS decimal(9,1)) = 9.8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9.8'"
"   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR([StemLength]*5)/5 AS decimal(9,1)) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10'"
165 more lines
```

I don't want the leading and trailing double-quotes for my query in SSMS.  I'm trying to become a RegEx power user so I searched for a solution using RegEx and found this excellent example here, https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/16898/issue-when-copypasting-from-excel-to-notepad

I'll summarize it here...

> **find what** = "([^"]*)"
> **replace with** = $1

I understand this solution except the $ in the replace.  Left to my own devices I would have come up with

> **find what** = "([^"]*)"
> **replace with** = \1

I tried this on my sample and it works as well.

My bible for using RegEx in NPP has always been this website, https://letconex.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in.html, and the site where the solution appeared had links to numerous resources as well.  Here's a very thorough post describing RegEx in NPP, https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-where-to-find-regular-expressions-regex-documentation

I haven't been able to find (well, understand, at least) a definitive answer to my question anywhere.

Is $ **always** the equivalent of \ in the replace string of a RegEx match (using Notepad++), or is my sample a special case of some sort?

Comment: Assuming the double quotes are the first and last characters in the string you could replace matches of `^"|"$` with an empty string.

Comment: To answer your question, yes. In NPP, `\1` and `$1` are the same when used as replacement text. NPP will accept either syntax.

Comment: Some regex implementations use `$number` instead of `\number` to refer to captured groups, in the replacement string.  They aren't equivalent in any other use - `$n` is nothing special, `\n` is a newline character.